# Print your code backwards - reverse quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

Write a program that prints its own source code out backwards, in other words an *eniuq*.

**Scoring:**

- +50 if you use pull data from the Internet.
- +25 if you read your own source code.
- +1 point per character
- Lowest score wins.

**Rules:**

- No using other files (e.g. `reverse.txt`)
- Minimum code length is two characters.
- **Your program cannot be a palindrome.**

Comment: Looks like [this has been done before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1364927/477682), just without the "no palindromes" rule.

Comment: Are those scores _bonuses_ or _penalties_? You need to specify in words if something is a penalty or a bonus, because saying `+10` can be taken to mean either "score as if it had 10 more characters than it actually does" or "the code can have 10 more characters that won't be scored", or other interpretations.

Comment: @AJMansfield Lowest score wins means that +x would be a penalty, -x would be a bonus.

Comment: They are penalties.

Comment: The one question I have, then, is why is pulling data from the internet given a larger penalty than reading the source file?

Comment: Woohoo, 1st place on the hot network questions list :D Our site needs more attention...

Comment: I posted the challenge http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16043/mirror-quine-or-my-head-hurts which has tighter rules than this one, so every answer there would qualify as an answer here, but would not score as well. My current answer there is over 6000 characters.

Comment: Next time this needs an extra rule about syntax errors (or possibly standard error).

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow There's good attention and bad attention. I don't think it's a coincidence that the quality of new questions just dropped considerably (and it wasn't that high to begin with).

Comment: When are you actually going to accept a solution?

Comment: I can't post an answer but can add a comment. Here's a solution in R. `reverse <- function() cat(paste(rev(strsplit(paste(deparse(get(as.character(match.call()[[1]]))), collapse="\n"),"")[[1]]), collapse=""))`. `reverse()` will print out `))"" = espalloc ,)]]1[[)"" ,)"n\" = espalloc        
 ,)))]]1[[)(llac.hctam(retcarahc.sa(teg(esraped(etsap(tilpsrts(ver(etsap(tac    
{
 )( noitcnuf` :P

Comment: @lebatsnok You could move your comment to an answer now. :)

Comment: This ruins Stack Cats...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

## GolfScript - 2

```
1
```

(ie `\n1` where `\n` is the newline character)

Output:

```
1
```

(ie `1\n`)

---

To quote [Ilmari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16021/print-your-code-backwards-reverse-quine/16040#16040):

> GolfScript automatically appends a newline to the end of the output

Thus a newline followed by a number will print the number followed by a newline.

Comment: +1 I didn't think anything could beat the Mathematica solution.

Comment: Pretty boring solution...

Comment: @theonlygusti It's golfscript, whaddya expect...

Answer (score 104):

### [huh?](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Huh%3F), 5 characters

```
!hcuO
```

<strike>I actually have NO idea how it works, but</strike> If you download the interpreter, and if you write `!hcuO`, then you get `Ouch!`

To run this, you need to execute the program like this:

```
huh.exe !hcuO
```

It will actually look for a file called `!hcuO`, but it doesn't exist, so it outputs `Ouch!`

Comment: +1 for writing something you don't understand

Comment: Is it not just a little ironic that you don't understand how your own code works, in an esolang that by design isn't supposed to understand your code either?

Comment: @Iszi That's the joke.

Comment: I'm not sure you're using `huh?` right, though I'm having a hard time finding proper documentation. It seems the usage is intended to be `huh.exe <path to source code>` and `Ouch!` is returned for an invalid path. Try putting your code into an actual file, and feeding that file as an argument to `huh?` and see what happens. It's also interesting to see that it generates a `Notes.txt` file with some commentary.

Comment: Ok, this thing just told me it thinks it understands but I didn't see anything happen. Maybe I should stop toying with it on my primary system.

Comment: What if there IS a file name !hcuO?

Answer (score 93):

## Mathematica, 3 chars

```
a 2
```

`a 2` means `a` times 2. So the answer is `2 a`.

Comment: This will probably win unless someone can get a two char solution.

Comment: In fact I know a two char solution. Also in Mathematica: `1#`. The output is `#1`.

Comment: @alephalpha: Then you should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 70):

### [H9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/H9%2B), 13 characters

```
!dlrow ,olleH
```

As the web page says, all characters that are not `H`, `9` or `+` are ignored, so my program will print `Hello, world!`

Comment: The one and only practical benefit of crazy esoteric languages is to answer these crazy questions.

Comment: It'd be more practical if these questions were so.

Comment: That's pretty darned clever!

Comment: According to the JS implementation, `H` seems to output `hello, world\n`, therefore your code should be `\ndlrow ,olleh`, with no bytes added.

Answer (score 46):

### Javascript: 34 characters

```
reifitnedi detcepxenU :rorrExatnyS
```

outputs `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, at least in the Chrome console

Comment: Clever use of abusing the system through error abuse

Comment: You sir, have made my day :D

Comment: Not an original idea, there already was [an answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16035/4269) about this in python 2.

Comment: @Lohoris Sorry, I didn't see that one

Comment: Firebug console in Mozilla Firefox: `tnemetats erofeb ; gnissim :rorrExatnyS` => `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`.

Answer (score 29):

## Python, <s>43</s> 41

```
_=']0~::[_%%_ tnirp;%r=_';print _%_[::~0]
```

Answer (score 27):

## Mathematica, 2 bytes

```
1#
```

Outputs:

> #1

Answer (score 22):

### TI-BASIC, 2

```
i2
```

Where `i` is the imaginary number.

Outputs `2i`

Comment: This only works in the home screen, not inside a PRGM.

Comment: @kernigh Did you try it? It works fine. (If the last statement of a TI-BASIC program evaluates as an expression, its result is printed instead of 'Done' when the program terminates)

Answer (score 19):

## BASIC, <s>22</s> <s>12</s> 7 characters

:-)

```
1 enil ni rorre xatnyS
```

**EDIT:** If you're allowed to enter the program in immediate mode, then this could be reduced to `rorre xatnyS` (12 characters).

In BBC BASIC, you only need 7 characters:

```
ekatsiM
```

Answer (score 17):

**ksh** (**21 chars**)

```
$ dnuof ton :found :hsk
ksh: dnuof: not found
```

---

**bash** (31 chars)

```
$ dnuof ton dnammoc :found :hsab-
-bash: dnuof: command not found
```

---

**sh** (29 chars)

```
$ dnuof ton dnammoc :found :hs-
sh: dnuof: command not found
```

This one could not work on some Linux distributions, but works on OSX.

---

**tcsh** (26 chars)

```
$ .dnuof ton dnammoC :found.
.dnuof: Command not found.
```

---

**csh** (26 chars)

```
% .dnuof ton dnammoC :found.
.dnuof: Command not found.
```

---

Above should work on all *unix based OS.

---

Assumptions:

- You don't have `dnuof` command or alias present.

---

**bash** (2-4 chars)

This one most likely doesn't qualify, but I'll share it as curiosity.

Assuming the previous shell command in Bash was `$!`. The following command:

```
!$
```

will produce: `$!`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, i have a command named `dnuof`

Comment: I forgot to add, it doesn't work on distributions which has `dnuof` installed (whatever it is). Damn hackers.

Comment: Hahaha, there's a command named `dnuof`? :D what does it do?

Comment: From the name I can tell ```dnuof``` = ```(d)aily (n)ew (u)ser (of)```. This outputs how many users have been created on this computer today. Its arguments filter which computer(s) on the Internet to show for the daily new users. (The computer names are decoded by the program; each computer is given a different name.) (```.dnuof``` is an alias for ```dnuof```.)

Comment: ha ha this is funny :))

Answer (score 15):

## C++ 472 characters

A lot of characters but I cant think of a simpler way in a c-based language.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#define p(t) std::cout<<'}'<<';'<<')'<<strrev(&std::string(#t)[0])<<t;
char* strrev(char*p){char*t=p;char*q=p;while(q&&*q)++q;for(--q;p<q;++p,--q)*p=*p^*q,*q=*p^*q,*p=*p^*q;return t;}
int main(){p("(p{)(niam tni};t nruter;q*^p*=p*,q*^p*=q*,q*^p*=p*)q--,p++;q<p;q--(rof;q++)q*&&q(elihw;p=q*rahc;p=t*rahc{)p*rahc(verrts *rahc;t<<)]0[)t#(gnirts::dts&(verrts<<')'<<';'<<'}'<<tuoc::dts )t(p enifed#>h.gnirts<edulcni#>maertsoi<edulcni#");}
```

Answer (score 12):

## Befunge 98 - 10 chars

```
"8k,'!1+,@
```

This works if your interpreter does not interpret wrapped lines after `"` as adding an extra space. If your interpreter does interpret wrapped lines like that, then this 11 char solution works ([because duplicate spaces in a string literal are interpreted as one](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html#Strings)):

```
"9k,'!1+,@
```

---

If I can use `g` without penalty, then these also work (7 and 8 chars respectively):

```
"5k,g,@
```

and

```
"6k,g,@
```

Answer (score 11):

### GolfScript, 12 chars

```
"-1%.`"-1%.`
```

This code takes the double-quoted string `` "-1%.`" ``, reverses it (`-1%`), duplicates it (`.`) and un-evals (`` ` ``) the second copy, restoring the double quotes around it.

#### Previous entry (13 chars):

```
{`'.~'+-1%}.~
```

Based on the 8-char quine `{'.~'}.~` from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/create-a-rotating-quine/5160#5160); the extra 5 chars are needed to stringify and reverse the output.

Ps. Note that GolfScript automatically appends a newline to the end of the output.  If this is counted as part of the output, a corresponding newline can be prepended to either version of the code without affecting the output, for a cost of one extra char.

Answer (score 11):

## [Fission](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission), 6 bytes

A rare case of a generalised quine that is the same length as [the normal quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50968/8478):

```
"LO+!'
```

The idea is the same as that of the normal quine, but we're using a left-going atom (starting at the `L`) so that print mode traverses the code in the opposite order.

Answer (score 10):

### Ruby, 60

```
puts(2,s=<<2.chop.reverse,s)
puts(2,s=<<2.chop.reverse,s)
2
```

Based on a classic Ruby quine.

Comment: Nice use of heredocs.

Answer (score 9):

### Perl, 41

```
$_=q{print~~reverse"\$_=q{$_};eval"};eval
```

Old 52 character answer (27+25 penalty)

```
open+0;print ~~ reverse <0>
```

Reads its own source, stores the reverse in a scalar, and prints that.

Comment: The `scalar` operator can be replaced by `~~`. However, you need to add +25 to your score for reading your own source code.

Comment: @breadbox noted

Comment: +1. I was about to post something like [my shell solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19797/2800): `$_='say"lave;\047",~~reverse,"\047=_\$"';eval`, but your solution is shorter :-) Note that you can golf it down to 39 characters using `say`. Hope you will beat all the [esoteric weirdness](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/286/2800) :-)

Comment: @Tomas are you suggesting replacing `print` with `say`? That ends up not printing anything.

Comment: Did you run perl with `-Mfeature=say` option?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't know if that would count against my score or not.

Answer (score 8):

## J: 26

**Standard quining** *(26 chars)*: by defining a function and passing it its own definition, in quotes:

```
|.(,],2#{:)'|.(,],2#{:)'''
```

Could probably be made shorter.

**J-specific** *(33 chars)*: by defining a variable and asking what file the variable was defined in, i.e. this one, then printing out the contents of that file:

```
1!:2&2|.1!:1(4!:4 a=:<'a'){4!:3''
```

Must be saved & run from a script (i.e. not in the REPL, because then the answer to the question is "your argument wasn't defined in a file", so there's no file to read).

Comment: The second one should get the + 25 bonus to read the own file.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: Penalty, but yeah.

Comment: "Bonus" sounds nicer.

Answer (score 8):

## [Microscript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript), 11 bytes

I kind of had to do this.

```
0"Caxq"Caxq
```

Surprisingly, this is actually shorter than the language's shortest known true quine. `q` and `a` are otherwise equivalent, except `q` adds wrapping quotes while `a` does not.

Answer (score 8):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 25 bytes

I was surprised to find this hadn't been done yet. :)

```
...yhsif sllems gnihtemoS
```

Paste code [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) and run it.

`.` is the Jump command, popping `x` and `y` off the stack, and moving the IP to `(x, y)` in the code box. In this case, the stack is empty, so the language's only error message is printed:

```
Something smells fishy...
```

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 5):

### PHP, 41 characters (+25)

Don't know if I understood the assignment correctly. But here's a PHP try:

```
while(!isset($s) || $s) echo isset($s) ? array_pop($s) : ($s = str_split(file_get_contents(__FILE__)) and null);
```

**edit:** this can be much shorter:

```
echo strrev(file_get_contents(__FILE__));
```

But since it can be that simple, this is probably not what is being asked...

Comment: phpFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fuy-mv0

Comment: When I click run, I get a whole bunch of useless nonsense (here is a short snippet of it: `>? ;)llun dna ))__ELIF__(f$(tilps_rts = s$( : )s$(pop_yarra ? )s$(tessi ohce )s$ || )s$(tessi!(elihw ;"stnetnoc_"=.f$ ;'teg_elif'=f$ php?<>?}};ESLAF nruter;"ec6x\i66x\02x\e47x\96x\rw `; there is much much more). Also, include your character count; this is a code golf. Also, it seems that you are reading your source file, so add 25 to your character count and that is your score. Lowest score wins.

Comment: @Quincunx First off, it is backwards ... but secondly, this is the source code that phpfiddle generates! (but backwards...) They seem to escape a lot of thing, trying to keep things safe. Replace `array_pop` with `array_shift` to see the source code not backwards...

Comment: Yes I can see the reversed source code, but what is with all the extraneous text? There are a lot of escape sequences, but there are some that aren't (eg: `ESLAF nruter` ie `return FALSE`).

Comment: @Quincunx Sorry, I'm not catching if you are showing interest in the way phpFiddle works, or if you are criticizing my code. If it's the latter, then in my defense, put my code in a .php file and run it in a browser, and it'll work cleanly. I just thought phpfiddle was a nice thing to let you see, so you can see a bit of it's inner workings.

Comment: Sorry if it seems I am criticizing. I was just confused by the extraneous detail. Also, with your new version, please state the character count (41) and include the +25 (for total of 66) for reading the file.

Comment: This is tagged as [tag:code-golf]

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript jQuery <del>119</del> <del>92</del> <del>74</del> 70  characters

```
alert($("#answer-16051 pre code").text().split("").reverse().join(""))
```

Now using jQuery, as minitech suggested in the comments, and manually wrapping with `<pre><code>` so I can use `text()` without fear of other code blocks in this post interfering. Manually wrapping with `<h4>` was incompatible with chromeium when I tested it, so now it should work in most browsers.

This program, if run from this page, finds the code block directly above, reverses its contents, and puts it in an alertbox.

Its easy enough to verify, just paste it into the dev console.

Comment: This is way longer than just using a function. And you should use jQuery (on this page) or at least `querySelector` anyways…

Comment: @minitech thanks for the tip, I swapped it for a `querySelector` now. I would like to look into the jQuery possibility, but it looks like it will take a little longer for me to figure out.

Comment: @minitech ok, thanks for the `jQuery` tip. (I only started learning javascript yesterday.)

Comment: I like this solution; thinking outside the box.

Answer (score 5):

## UNIX shell, 31

Real solution at **52 characters:**

```
A='printf "A$ lave;\047`echo $A|rev`\047=A"';eval $A
```

But beware! Honesty doesn't pay off in today's world! Penalty is too low!!

**6 chars + 25 = 31:**

```
rev $0
```

Comment: On OSX `rev $0` generates the error: `rev: illegal option -- b`.

Answer (score 4):

### MATLAB, 78 characters:

```
 
|
.snoisserpxe ro stnemetats BALTAM ni dilav ton si retcarahc tupni ehT :rorrE
```

Note that the solution requires you to begin with a special character (alt+0160) and that it prints exactly the reversed message. (Unlike the python solution)

Answer (score 4):

### MS-DOS, 24 bytes

```
eman elif ro dnammoc daB
```

Output:

```
Bad command or file name
```

Answer (score 4):

## Windows 10 .EXE, 98 bytes

```
.rehsilbup erawtfos eht htiw kcehc ,CP ruoy htiw noisrev a dnif oT

.CP ruoy no nur t'nac ppa sihT
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a version for my PC?

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 62

```
function f(){alert((f+'f()').split('').reverse().join(''))}f()
```

Works for me on latest Chrome (v 31.0.1650.63). Some other browsers may give a different output. (If you reverse that output, then it would work :P)

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, <s>118</s> 102 bytes

```
FOR I=-101TO.?MID$(("+CHR$(34))*3,30,102)[-I];:NEXTFOR I=-100TO.?MID$(("+CHR$(34))*3,30,102)[-I];:NEXT
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
"iQ ²w"iQ ²w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XykzUOHQpnIo9f8/AA)

Based off the [standard Japt quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71932/39244)

#### Explanation

```
"iQ ²w"      // Take this string.        iQ ²w
       iQ    // Insert a quote.          "iQ ²w
          ²  // Double.                  "iQ ²w"iQ ²w
           w // Reverse.                 w² Qi"w² Qi"
             // Implicitly output.
```

Comment: Congrats on your 5th Japt solution; bounty on its way.

Comment: @Shaggy wait >_> I wasn't doing this for the bounty

Comment: Happy coincidentally for you, so, that there's one going :)

Answer (score 3):

## Windows command prompt, 93 bytes

```
.elif hctab ro margorp elbarepo ,dnammoc lanretxe ro lanretni na sa dezingocer ton si 'file.'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 56

```
($=_=>_!=$._?_?$(_.slice(1))+_[0]:')':$('($='+$+')('))()
```

Comment: Please state your environment because this does not work in Chrome. Is this Rhino or what?

Comment: @GeorgeReith: Anything with ES6 arrow function support. All SpiderMonkeys should work fine, for example (Rhino included).

Answer (score 2):

### C, 148

```
char *a="};)43,b,43,a(ftnirp;]i-57[a=]i[b)++i;67<i;(rof{)(niam;i,]99[b,%c%s%c=a* rahc",b[99],i;main(){for(;i<76;i++)b[i]=a[75-i];printf(a,34,b,34);}
```

Just a fun play on a typical C quine.

Answer (score 2):

## CSS, 88 bytes

```
<style>:before,*{display:block;unicode-bidi:bidi-override;direction:rtl;content:'<style>
```

Put in a blank html page to avoid conflict with other tags.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>53</s> <s>50</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
q=_=>("q="+q+";q()").split("").reverse().join("");q()
```

```
(q=_=>`(q=${q})()`.split("").reverse().join(""))()
```

```
(q=_=>`(q=${q})()`.split``.reverse().join``)()
```

```
(q=_=>[...`(q=${q})()`].reverse().join``)()
```

Please help me shorten this up.

Comment: You don't need the wrapper. ```q=_=>[...`q=${q}`].reverse().join`` ``` works just as well.

Comment: If I remove the wrapper, it will not automatically execute itself.

Comment: it doesn't need to.  Functions are fine.

Comment: But then, the code returns the function reference, not the output of the function.

Comment: @ericw31415 is right. the function call is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 4 bytes

```
KNU_
```

`K` prints `_UNK`, `N` pushes `None`, and `U` pushes `0`. And `_` pops the top value on the stack (but doesn't print). So only `_UNK` is printed.

Comment: Why does `K` output `_UNK`?

Comment: @RandomUser ask Riker for more details, he's the language's creator. I just read the docs.

Answer (score 2):

## Brain-Flak, 3836 + 3 = 3839

```
(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(()())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()){({}<>)<>}<>([]){({}[()]<(({}[()]<((((((((()()()()()){}){}){})<>))()))>)<>){({}[()]<({}())>){({}[()]<({}(((()()())){}{}){}())>){({}[()]<({}()())>){({}[()]<({}(((()()()){}()){}){}())>){({}[()]<({}()())>){({}[()]<({}(((()()()()())){}{}){})>){(<{}({}()())>)}}}}}}}{}([]<({}<{({}<>)<>}<>>)>){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}{({}[()]<((({}[()])()))>)}{}<>>)}{}{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@q@hoYkMNTUgGF0Muwig3arNYRCEodeBH7sBIdk5jCchPTvjywEbkxbBMTOippS@Z20fhrjirU/@OjaNyzE5c1ueOaLEH9fHse7dNAuf5ai4cufLWWJVcl6P64yY/GfJE6cjaqd7aeaXKnn13rf16q@Ca6hgpr8CraaU3o3p8Hc99e89qqLjqu53FmxVydk7j/rVWGXhIsaeU3sx006ELTWZqdKd9oBiCoTkQponW1Y3XxhfBYtGGJFGQbgM0s65JUigCpj1ZY6NwKId@D2E76BcPB2XvdEFCbP6xIAfZr44nEjLIV9Ind9gDFtSG2@FKoCCJGQj0lrf7g8)

+3 bytes from the `-A` flag

This is a very simple variation on the standard [Brain-Flak Quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95296/56656).   In fact this variant is obtained by *removing bytes* from the original Quine.  Here is a picture of the original Quine with the removed characters in red:

[image: Code difference]

The reason this variation is so simple is that the original Quine builds two parts of the program each on its own stack.  One of the two parts is reversed so that when they are joined it becomes un-reversed.

So to make the reverse Quine we simply remove a stack swap.

We also have to remove the part of the program that encodes these two bytes otherwise they will be printed as well.

Comment: How come the `-A` flag is 3 bytes?

Comment: @MDXF The flag is ` -A` you need to add a space to call.  For programs that take input you only need plus one because `-f` can become `-fA` for one extra byte.

Comment: I thought the general concensus on compiler/interpreter flags was that they did not have to include the space or the `-` in the byte count.

Comment: @MDXF No, you do have to include them.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 115 bytes

```
f(){char*s="f(){char*s=c%s%c%;printf(s+42,34,a,34);};)43,s,43,24+s(ftnirp;%c%s%c=s*rahc{)(f";printf(s+42,34,s,34);}
```

Haha, this is possible in C! Took me a few hours and nearly cheats, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 49 characters

(Note: the actual program is three lines long, the third line being empty.)

```
print$/,~~reverse<<''x2
print$/,~~reverse<<''x2
```

Newlines can be a little unintuitive when text is reversed: the output starts with two blank lines. A naive user might expect the output to look more like this program, which is actually significantly shorter:

```
say~~reverse<< x2
say~~reverse<< x2
```

But only first listing is actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket 178

```
(let((l(list->string(reverse(string->list"(let((l(list->string(reverse(string->lista~a~a~))))(q (integer->char 34)))(printf l q l q))"))))(q (integer->char 34)))(printf l q l q))
```

Output:

```
))q l q l ftnirp()))43 rahc>-regetni( q())))"))q l q l ftnirp()))43 rahc>-regetni( q())))~a~a~atsil>-gnirts(esrever(gnirts>-tsil(l((tel("tsil>-gnirts(esrever(gnirts>-tsil(l((tel(
```

Using the powerful `printf` makes it almost cheating (though I see people pulling their own sources for *only 25 penalty*.)

Answer (score 1):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax),22 bytes

This is a variant of my [beeswax quine (golf you a quine for great good!)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67994/43477), also using beeswax’ ability to modify its own code.

```
J~@D@~1~M.8~3@.+~++~4*
```

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl) to my beeswax interpreter written in Julia.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @JoKing by using `'` strings instead of `"` strings*

```
'd3*}>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xz3FWKvWLt/m/38A)

#### Explanation

```
'd3*}>o<               Push the code points of every character in the string 'd3*}>o<'
d3*                    Computes 39, the code point of ' (13*3)
                       Now the stack contains the quote on top of the stack
}                      Shift the stack to the right, so that the ' will be shifted to the bottom of the stack
                       This is required because the ' needs to be printed last
>o<                    Print everything in the stack until the stack is empty
                       And finally the program ends in an error
```

Comment: Would `00g` (rather than `84*2+`) count as reading the source code?

Comment: @Challenger5 I would think so.

Comment: How about you use `'` instead? [`'d3*}>o<`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xz3FWKvWLt/m/38A)?

Comment: @JoKing Thanks, that was a neat find

Answer (score 1):

## [Apple ][ BASIC](https://www.scullinsteel.com/apple2/), 12 bytes

```
RORRE XATNYS?
```

Hit the soft <kbd>RESET</kbd> key on the emulator to enter BASIC mode.

[image: applejs]

## [Commodore 64 BASIC](//c64js.com), 13 bytes

```
RORRE  XATNYS?
```

[image: c64js]

Comment: @user56656 Being my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105688/29325 invalid, this one should be too.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Being my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105688/29325 invalid, this one should be too.

Comment: @ike Being my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105688/29325 invalid, this one should be too.

Comment: @sergiol just leaving the comment should be fine (as opposed to pinging three people), I'm willing to delete this if it's invalid. However I disagree that error quines are not allowed by default; this is not asking for a quine, rather a quine variant. I've long thought those two tags should be differentiated.

Comment: Additionally, this program defines its own rules for what constitutes as a valid submission as opposed to going along with the "proper quine" rules discussed on the meta.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 12 bytes

```
{"~_"\`W%}_~
```

Explanation:

```
{             e# Push this block literal:
 "~_"         e#   Push the string "~_"
     \        e#   Swap
      `       e#   Escape
       W%     e#   Reverse
         }    e# End
          _   e# Duplicate
           ~  e# Execute
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), 11 bytes

```
"@o&l]=43#"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9fySFfLSfW1sRYWen/fwA)

#### Explanation

In Wumpus, the IP gets reflected off the boundaries of the grid, so without any further control flow redirection, a program on a single line will bounce back and forth through the code.

```
"@o&l]=43#"    Push the individual code points of this string to the stack.
               This gives us the entire code except the quotes.
               The IP then bounces off the end and starts moving back through
               the code. Since the " ended string mode, this time around the
               code will actually be executed.
#34            Push 34, the code point of double quotes.
=              Duplicate.
]              Shift one copy to the bottom of the stack.
l              Push the stack depth (i.e. the program length 11).
&o             Print that many characters.
@              Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
s="print's cexe;%r=s'%s[::-1]";exec s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/n6vYVqmgKDOvRL1YITm1ItVatci2WF21ONrKStcwVskaKJSsUPz/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 3 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
£↕o
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.2/JstxGWT.html?code=wqPihpVv)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 42 bytes

```javascript
(f=([a,...b]=`(f=${f})()`)=>a?f(b)+a:'')()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctBCsIwEEDRvafIQugEdboXondwK8JM2klJKZmSlIKIZ48Bl//Bn3nnMuS4bpeko9RBU9FFcNEJKgQHTz4jon85anX8hK8FS9bd@B7A2xNfu65JxbIucSPCLLvkImBx1piITN@bx98MTxyTCZpNFh6jj215H2z9AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 6 bytes

```
"2ss}H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X8mouLjW4/9/AA)

Same as regular [Gol><> quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160994/78410), except that we just put the 34 at the bottom of the stack, instead of flipping the entire stack.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 7 bytes

```
!RORRER
```

[Link to interpreter](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/) (paste the code above, link removes the `!` and `O`)

**Explanation:**

The interpreter ignores characters other than `R`,`r`,`E`,`e` so the code is:

```
RRRER
```

Now to put the code in explanation:

```
  RE  # Push 0
RR    # (RR flag: doesn't exist)
    R # R doesn't exist, so output RERROR!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0"D34çýR"D34çýR
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7g@CM//8B)

Or **17 bytes** if a default trailing newline isn't allowed:

```
0"D34çýR?"D34çýR?
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7g@wRrP//AQ)

Modification of the default [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) [`0"D34çý"D34çý`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97899/52210) by adding `R`.

**Explanation:**

```python
0                   # Push 0 to the stack
                    #  STACK: [0]
 "D34çýR"           # Push the string 'D34çýR' to the stack
                    #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýR']
          D         # Duplicate this string
                    #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýR', 'D34çýR']
           34ç      # Push '"' to the stack
                    #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýR', 'D34çýR', '"']
              ý     # Join the stack by this '"' delimiter
                    #  STACK: ['0"D34çýR"D34çýR']
               R    # Reverse the top value on the stack:
                    #  STACK ['Rýç43D"Rýç43D"0']
                    # (Output the top of the stack implicitly)
```

Comment: Your first [TIO link](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7PQ8vRWL@/w/mAwA) is returning `1` for me. I assume you're avoiding the [boring 2-byte solution](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@fy/D/fwA)? :P

Comment: @Oliver Ah, my first TIO link was a copy-paste error from another quine challenge (the one that checks if an input is a substring of the program itself). I've fixed the TIO link, thanks for noticing. As for the 2-byte solution, that is no longer considered a valid quine in the current meta. [More information about it here.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/we-need-a-new-proper-quine-definition)

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 142 bytes

```
select
reverse(replace('@''[@'||chr(93)||'''))from dual;','@',q'[select
reverse(replace('@''[@'||chr(93)||'''))from dual;','@',q]'))from dual;
```

## Oracle SQL, 118 bytes

```
select
reverse(substr(rpad(1,144,'||chr(39)),27))from dual;select
reverse(substr(rpad(1,144,'||chr(39)),27))from dual;
```

Test in SQL Plus

```
SQL> set lines 80 pages 0
SQL> select
  2  reverse(replace('@''[@'||chr(93)||'''))from dual;','@',q'[select
  3  reverse(replace('@''[@'||chr(93)||'''))from dual;','@',q]'))from dual;
;laud morf))']q,'@',';laud morf))'''||)39(rhc||'@[''@'(ecalper(esrever
tceles['q,'@',';laud morf))'''||)39(rhc||'@[''@'(ecalper(esrever
tceles


SQL> select
  2  reverse(substr(rpad(1,144,'||chr(39)),27))from dual;select
  3  reverse(substr(rpad(1,144,'||chr(39)),27))from dual;
;laud morf))72,))93(rhc||',441,1(dapr(rtsbus(esrever
tceles;laud morf))72,))93(rhc||',441,1(dapr(rtsbus(esrever
tceles
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 6 bytes

```
sP#Hr"
```

This is just another way of doing a reverse quine, similar to Bubbler's answer

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/vzhA2aNI6f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
f=([c,...s]='f='+f)=>c?f(s)+c:''
```

Recursively reverses the string by first providing the quine as the default argument.  This beats the [syntax error](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16044/57013) version, which isn't even consistent between browsers.

Answer (score 1):

## [MS SQL Server 2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-technical-documentation?view=sql-server-2017), 173 bytes

```sql
declare @ char=1
select
reverse(substring(left(@+replicate('+char(39),3),201),28,174))
declare @ char=1
select
reverse(substring(left(@+replicate('+char(39),3),201),28,174))
```

**Output:**

```
))471,82,)102,)3,)93(rahc+'(etacilper+@(tfel(gnirtsbus(esrever
tceles
1=rahc @ eralced
))471,82,)102,)3,)93(rahc+'(etacilper+@(tfel(gnirtsbus(esrever
tceles
1=rahc @ eralced
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=dfc54a558fdc7f7f5816de29bf6b5b1e)!

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 16 bytes (SBCS)

```
`÷^℠⅀:,.`÷^℠⅀:,.
```

Outputs:

```
.,:⅀℠^÷`.,:⅀℠^÷`
```

### Explained

```
`÷^℠⅀:,.`÷^℠⅀:,.

`÷^℠⅀:,.`           #Push the string '÷^℠⅀:,.'
÷^                  #Item split string and reverse stack
℠⅀                  #Summate it all into a string
:,.                 #Standard Keg quine procedure
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/4fD2uEctCx61Nljp6KFw/v8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 6 bytes

```
`IṘ`IṘ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJEIiwiIiwiYEnhuZhgSeG5mCIsIiIsIiJd)

### Explained

```
`IṘ`IṘ
`IṘ`   # The string "IṘ"
    I  # appended to a backtick-surrounded version of itself
     Ṙ # Reversed
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 59

34 + 25 for reading own sourcecode.

```
<?=strrev(join(file((__FILE__))));
```

<kbd>[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/80862)</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't this get the 25 penalty?

Comment: @ike you're right, I edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 33+25=58

```
print File.read(__FILE__).reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 31 Characters

```
'''' raen rorre xatnys :1:tupni
```

Comment: Looks like lua to me, on LUA it says `STDIN:1: syntax error near 'rorre'`

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, 111

```
function d=g();d='gvodujpo!e>h)*<e>(<e>gmjqms)\e)2;29*.2-e-e)29;foe*.2^*<';d=fliplr([d(1:18)-1,d,d(18:end)-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 8 + 25 for reading source = 33 bytes

```
rev "$0"
```

31 for no space in path to file

```
rev $0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Help, WarDoq!](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Help,_WarDoq!), 2 bytes + 25 = 27

```
 q
```

The space is needed.

> - Minimum code length is two characters.

Comment: This reads its own source code via the `q` built-in, so I think this is subject to the **+25 bytes** penalty.

Comment: @Dennis I will add them. Thanks for pointing, although there is no other way to make quines here.

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes

```
"9&o57*to@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@69kqZZvaq5Vku/w/z8A)

#### Explanation

```
"9&o57*to@"   Push code points of the entire program except the " to the stack.
9&            Execute the next command 9 times.
o             Print 9 characters from top to bottom (i.e. in reverse order).
57*           Compute 5*7 = 35.
t             Decrement to 34 (the code point of ").
o             Print the quote.
@             Terminate the program.
```

I'm not 100% sure whether this is optimal. 4 bytes to compute `34` seems painful and while I've found a whole bunch of 4-byte alternatives, I haven't found anything in 3 bytes yet. Some of those alternatives (some of these give other results, but they're 34 (mod 256)):

```
aN4Y
7aRY
5R1Y
4Pa+
7PYN
```

Answer (score 0):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

```
"W%_`"W%_`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/XylcNT4BTPz/DwA)

Alternatively:

```
"`W%_"_W%`
```

#### Explanation

```
"W%_`"   e# Push this string which contains the code after the string.
W%       e# Reverse the string.
_        e# Duplicate it.
`        e# Stringify the copy which wraps it in quotes. The unquoted and
         e# quoted versions are then implicitly printed to STDOUT back to back.
```

In the alternative solution, the string itself already contains the code in reverse and then we only reverse the copy (i.e. the string representation). It's kinda neat that it's then just one character off from being a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8 (function), 144 bytes

```java
v->{String s="v->{String s=%c%s%1$c;return new StringBuffer(s.format(s,34,s)).reverse();}";return new StringBuffer(s.format(s,34,s)).reverse();}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nY9BawIxFITv/oqHuJCABqS9LfbQu14EL6WHNL4t0ezbJe8lIrK/fY11L157GRiGGeY72WxXXY90Op5HFywzbK2n2wzAk2BsrEPYPSzAXqKn38/UNBjBqUPnj5B1XbJhBkVZrHgHOyDYwJhXH7dnA3gzf3GVq7haL1wdUVIkILy8jCs2TRdbK4qXb@9L1tpEzBgZla6H@f9qY/13sk8/oZycvuYHQ1uA1XPo69vqCfbKgq3pkpi@JBJIkXGKUgh6Yh7GOw)

## Java 8 (full program), 240 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s="interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.print(new StringBuffer(s.format(s,34,s)).reverse());}}";System.out.print(new StringBuffer(s.format(s,34,s)).reverse());}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pYxBCsIwEEWvEoqBBGpAdFfcuHfVpbgY0omkkqRkphEpPXsUegJx9@G990cosE8TxnF41uojY3ZgUVwXYmBvRUl@EAF8VD1nHx@3O@hlm4LOzc@FtJLkYWe7/k2MwaSZzfRlrCK@xKZdZucwKzIu5QCsqD2eWtLaZCyYCZXW3bo2/1/U@gE)

**Explanation:**

- The `String s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together.

And then `new StringBuffer(...).reverse()` is used to reverse this source code.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 66 bytes

```hs
main=putStr$reverse$s++show s;s="main=putStr$reverse$s++show s;s="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIpSi1LLWoOFWlWFu7OCO/XKHYuthWiaCC//8B)

Comment: 64 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIpTgjv1yhWFu72LrYtii1LLWoOFWJkPz//wA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 38 bytes

```
puts [string rev [read [open $argv0]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCG6uKQoMy9doSi1TCG6KDUxRSE6vyA1T0ElsSi9zCA2Nvb///8WAA)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 24 Bytes

```
(|.@,quote)'(|.@,quote)'
```

Evaluates to the string `')etouq,@.|(')etouq,@.|(`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19Bo0bPQaewNL8kVVMdmc0Fk1XQtVJQ0tNUQJFF5agr@DnpKbjkpxYrlGSkKhSllqUWFaeCNGsq5CaWJGcoaOhaaSpklhQD5YpLc0oUNIAm2v//DwA) Uses `echo` in order to print result.

Alternatively, if a full program is required:

```
(echo@|.@,quote)'(echo@|.@,quote)'
```

Is 34 bytes and prints `')etouq,@.|@ohce(')etouq,@.|@ohce(`

#### Explanation:

Both of these work in the same way:

```
(|.@,quote)'(|.@,quote)' | Expression to be evaluated
           '(|.@,quote)' | String literal containing the code
(         )              | Hook, (f g) y is evaluated as y f (g y)
     quote               | Wrap the string in quotes
    ,                    | Append to the unquoted version
 |.@                     | Reverse the whole thing
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 bytes

```
"r34b4l"r34b4l
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%22r34b4l%22r34b4l&i=&a=1)

Yet another adaption of the `"34bL"34bL` quine.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Q9/9/AA)

Short but boring.

`1` gets ignored when `-` makes `-1` the argument which gets printed.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
“ṚṾȮ”ȮṾṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO2c93LnvxLpHDXNPrAOygPz//wE)

(More) interesting but long.

`“ṚṾȮ”` is a string literal for `ṚṾȮ`. `Ȯ` prints the string and returns it. `Ṿ` unevals the string, yielding the string `“ṚṾȮ”` (with the quote characters `“”` as part of the string). `Ṛ` reverses this string and its result, `”ȮṾṚ“` implicitly gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 13 bytes

```
">:#,_98+2*,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNZNS0rK/P9fyc5KWSfe0kLbSEvH4f9/AA)

Relies on nonstandard interpreter behavior. Works pretty much the same as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106791/51657), except it's reversed.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 36 bytes

```powershell
&($f={&{-join"&(`$f={$f})"[35..0]}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fTUMlzbZarVo3Kz8zT0lNIwHEVUmr1VSKNjbV0zOIra3V/P8fAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 48 bytes

```julia
(a=:(print(reverse("(a=:($(a)))|>eval"))))|>eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XyPR1kqjoCgzr0SjKLUstag4VUMJLKaikaipqVljl1qWmKOkCWf@B6vNyYOrLkosV1JS4uIi1SAuLqA2Tc3/AA)

based on [this quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92455)

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 52 bytes

```julia
"]esrever∘wohs,tnirp[>|.".|>[print,show∘reverse]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/Xyk2tbgotSy16FHHjPL8jGKdkrzMooJouxo9Jb0au@iCosy8Ep3ijPxyoDxYXXFq7H8usHBOngZURENJSYmLixyjgLqUlDQ1/wMA)

based on [this quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178441)