# Backwards and forwards polyglot quine!

Tags: code-golf, quine, polyglot

You must make a polyglot that outputs its source code in one language and its source code *backward* in another. Unlike the normal rules, you are allowed to read the current file or use a builtin to get the source code of your submission and reverse that in one language. **Your source code cannot be a palindrome.**

For example, if your source code is `abcxyz`, it must output `abcxyz` in one language and `zyxcba` in another. If your code is `abcxyzyxbca`, it's invalid because it's a palindrome.

Good luck!

Comment: Normal rules are there for a reason. Allowing quine built-ins will likely make this challenge too broad, and allowing palindrome source codes allows answers which are forward quines for both languages.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer palindromes are now not allowed.

Comment: _Palindromes are not allowed_ What does that mean? Are you trying to forbid built-in functions that reverse their input, maybe?

Comment: @LuisMendo No I suggested that if palindromes are allowed then a forward quine+forward quine polyglot could be a valid answer (while not being the intention). Reverse functions aren't banned.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Ah, so the _source code_ cannot be a palindrome?

Comment: @programmer5000 Well, I don't think it's too broad anymore.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, I'll clarify and add an example in there.

Comment: @programmer5000 Are different versions of a language considered the same language or not?

Comment: @LuisMendo you are correct.

Comment: @ErikTheOutgolfer different versions of the same language are allowed.

Comment: I think you should offer a bounty for the first person to complete this challenge without breaking any of the normal quine rules. (maybe 50 rep?)

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp good idea. Maybe.

Comment: I read "in one language" as clearly disallowing the case where both languages read the source code, but the current top-voted answer does exactly that. Can you edit to make it clear whether that's meant to be allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PHP & GolfScript, 2 bytes

```
1
```

i.e. a newline and the digit 1.

This is a reverse quine in [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), [contributed on this site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16021/print-your-code-backwards-reverse-quine/16088#16088) by [Justin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9498/justin). PHP hasn't triggered that it's a programming language so it prints its input.

Answer (score 5):

### Batch / bash + tac, 39 bytes

```
:;tac -r -s '.\|'$'\n' $0;exit
@type %0
```

Outputs forwards in Batch. Explanation: Batch sees the first line as a label and ignores it, while the second line simply copies the source file to STDOUT. (Note that you need to invoke the file including extension, or change `%0` to `%~f0`.) `bash` sees four commands:

- `:` does nothing (same as `true`)
- `tac -r -s '.\|'$'\n' $0`

  - `-r` puts `tac` into regex mode
  - `-s` specifies a regex
  - `'.\|'$'\n'` is the regex, composed of

    - `.` any character except newline
    - `\|` or
    - `$'\n'` a newline
  - The upshot is that `tac` splits the file into characters rather than lines.
- `exit` stops the script, ignoring the fourth command
- `@type %0` (ignored)

Comment: I think that you can replace the first line with `:;rev $0|tac;exit`. Also, the header should say **Batch / sh + util-linux + coreutils** instead.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `$'\n'` is a Bashism, `rev $0|tac` doesn't reverse newlines correctly, and does it really matter that `tac` comes in a package?

Comment: `$'\n'` doesn't exist in the replacement I've suggested, and `rev $0|tac` works for me. And I think it's better to specify the packages instead of the individual utilities, because sometimes confusion might arise (e.g. which package's `tac`?).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@29lXZRapqBiUFOSmGydWpFZwuVQUlmQqqBq8P8/AA "Bash – TIO Nexus") is wrong. So is [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@29lXZRapqBiUFOSmGydWpFZwuVQUlmQqqBqwPX/PwA "Bash – TIO Nexus") (but more subtly).

Comment: Could you please give an explanation?

Comment: @Neil Oh I see, I was tricked by a trailing newline.

Comment: @programmer5000 Something like that?

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 / Python 3, 71 bytes

```
lambda _='lambda _=%r:(_%%_)[::int(1-(1/2)*4)]':(_%_)[::int(1-(1/2)*4)]
```

Does not use any quine builtins.

Thanks to ovs for generally awakening me.

Comment: `lambda _='lambda _=%r:(_%%_)[::int(1-(1/2)*4)]':(_%_)[::int(1-(1/2)*4)]` for 71 bytes

Comment: @ovs Oh of course, how I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

## JS (ES5), JS (ES6), 94 bytes

```
function f(){try{eval("x=(f+'f()').split``.reverse().join``")}catch(e){x=f+"f()"};return x}f()
```

Does not use any quine built-ins. Just uses the fact that JS functions stringify to their code. Probably can be golfed more.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP & Retina, 2 bytes

```
1
```

The same as Gille's PHP & GolfScript answer.

PHP just reads the code and outputs it directly, Retina will replace matches of an empty string in the input and replace it with 1, and output that with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow reading the source code, it isn't really a quine.

### PHP & sh+util-linux, 6 bytes

```
rev $0
```

I'm sure that the usual golfing languages can do it in 2 bytes.

Comment: They infact can.