# Period 2 Reversed Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

Your task is to write a program that outputs its own source code in reverse. However, when the reversed code is run, it should output the source code, facing the correct direction.

### Example

Say your program is `abc`. When run, it should output `cba`. `cba`, when run, should output `abc`.

### Rules

Your program should follow all the rules of a [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878) (except for outputting the source code).
Palindromes are disallowed.

Random note:
I am aware of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8595#8595) but I believe that this challenge is different because the transformed code must have the same properties.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16021/print-your-code-backwards-reverse-quine?rq=1)

Comment: [Also related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2582/8478)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 3 bytes

```
1
2
```

*Thanks to @MartinEnder for reminding me about [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103262/12012).*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@2/IZfT/PwA)

#### How it works

This exploits a potential flaw in our [definition of proper quine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4878/12012):

> It must be possible to identify a section of the program which encodes a different part of the program. ("Different" meaning that the two parts appear in different positions.)
>
> Furthermore, a quine must not access its own source, directly or indirectly.

That's obviously the case here, as the output is the reverse of the code and the code is not a palindrome.

RProgN – *reverse* programmer notation – uses a LIFO stack and prints the items on it in the order they are popped. The two tokens **1** and **2**, separated by spaces and/or newlines, get popped in reverse order and are printed separated by a newline.

This prints the reversed program

```
2
1
```

which, in turn, prints the original one.

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@2/EZfj/PwA)

Comment: I like the URL.

Comment: We should get this fixed... I'd post a new answer (based on [this comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878#comment37588_4878)) on the meta question, but it probably wouldn't get enough attention to compete with the existing answers.

Comment: @ETHproductions: Do it. I feel there are several problems with our current proper quine definition. (Arguably, my language 7 is a study in edge cases for proper quineness; in addition to this particular case, it can handle quite a few others.) FWIW, I'm not sure this is a proper reverse-quine even by our current definition; the 1 and 2 are clearly encoded by themselves, so the only potential interest is as to what's encoding the newline. (This is different from a `1\n1`, in which the two `1`s encode each other; that's possibly a proper quine but not a proper reverse-quine.)

Answer (score 10):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 33 bytes

```
b3*>1#;-:0g,:#;_@_;#:,g0:-;#1>*b3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@59krGVnqGyta2WQrmOlbB3vEG@tbKWTbmCla61saKeVZPz/v6GRMQA)

Comment: Nice first answer. But use the `#` to make you header. Also go to Tryitonline.net and get a online interpreter

Comment: Also go under the save button and use the codegolf submission one.

Comment: I edited it on TIO in the first place I just forgot to add the link but now its added and thanks for the Header tip

Comment: Note that the "codegolf submission" option on TIO gives you a starting template, including the header.

Comment: I thought `g` was disallowed in Befunge quines, as it reads the program's source directly from memory?

Comment: I'm not sure but the Quines on wikipedia use it so I quess its allowed

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't care about PPCG's [Proper Quine definition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878#4878).

Answer (score 7):

### [Fission 2](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), 10 bytes

```
"L;L'!+!'_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fission2#@6/kY@2jrqitqB7//z8A)

This prints:

```
_'!+!'L;L"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fission2#@x@vrqitqO5j7aP0/z8A)

And vice versa.

#### Explanation

This is a modification of the [reverse quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50970/8478). It's working to our advantage here that `!` is used for printing and is also only one code point away from the the quote `"`. That makes it easier to make the quote printing section palindromic (the `'!+!'`). Let's start with the first code:

```
"L;L'!+!'_
```

This program has two entry points at the `L`s, which each creates a left-going atom. However, the right one immediately hits the `;` which destroys it. The left one enters string mode and wraps around to the end, so that it prints the entire code (except the `"`) from back to front. That already gives us `_'!+!'L;L`. All that's left is to print the `"`. `_` can be ignored, `'!` sets the atom's mass to 33 (the code point of `!`), `+` increments it to `"`, and `!` prints it. That's all the output done. The `'L` sets the atoms mass to the code point of `L` but that's irrelevant. `;` destroys this atom as well and since no atoms are left, the program terminates.

Now the other way round:

```
_'!+!'L;L"
```

Again, we have two entry points but one atom is immediately destroyed. This time we move through the `!+!'` section first, so we start by printing a quote. The `'_` is again irrelevant, but we need the `_` (or some other useless character) here to avoid `'` escaping the `"`. The atom wraps to the end, traverses the source code once in string mode to print the rest of the program in reverse, the `L` is then ignored and `;` destroys the atom and terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

## <><, 19 bytes

```
"rf2+2*rol?!;70.05;!?lor*d3r'
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiXCJyZjIrMipyb2w/ITs3MC4wNTshP2xvcipkM3InIiwiaW5wdXQiOiJiYmJhY2RlZmFhYSIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwibW9kZSI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

**Reversed**

```
'r3d*rol?!;50.07;!?lor*2+2fr"
```

[it yrT](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJ3IzZCpyb2w/ITs1MC4wNzshP2xvcioyKzJmclwiIiwiaW5wdXQiOiJiYmJhY2RlZmFhYSIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwibW9kZSI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

So I'm not super sure if this is a proper quine. Let me know what your opinion is, I'll delete the post if people think it's invalid.

I use the `'` to switch into quoting mode that will push the code raw into the stack. Then when the pointer wraps around it will exit the quote again. However, I do need to manually add the `'` quote character at the end as `d3*`, and `"` as `rf2+2`. These would count as "code that encodes a different part of the program".