# Implement ROT-47... in ROT-47

Tags: code-challenge, cryptography

Challenge: Implement [ROT-47](http://rot47.net/) in code that works as both itself and as the ROT-47 version of itself.

#### Scoring:

Your score is calculated as a percentage of **used, ROT-47 eligible bytes in total of both versions of the program** divided by **total bytes (all characters) of both versions**.

A **used, ROT-47 eligible byte** is any character that would be converted by the ROT-47 cipher that is not **part of a comment** or ignored by the compiler/interpreter. For example, any character in a brainfuck program that is not `+-<>[],.`  is not considered a used byte, and any character in a C program including and after `//` or inside `/* */` is not considered a used byte. All special symbols in APL are not considered used, as are all characters in a Whitespace program (sorry).

Ties will be broken by the program with the most upvotes. If there is still a tie, then the shortest program wins.

Example scoring:

#### C: 62/64 = 96.875%

Notice there is a space in this program. Obviously also, this program is not a valid entry because it doesn't even compile, but I wanted to show how scoring works.

```
main(){printf("Hello World!");}
```

Comment: And what language does `>2:?WXLAC:?E7WQw6==@ (@C=5PQXjN` compile in?

Comment: @hosch250 lol, that was just a dumb example

Comment: By "ROT-47 eligible" do you mean "in the ASCII range 33 to 126"?  I.e. if my C program has spaces or newlines or tabs, do those count as ROT-47 eligible or not? What about the fact that some spaces are essential in order for a program to function in many languages - do those not count as used because they are not R47-eligible, even though the program would break without them?

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre The spaces or newlines or tabs don't count because I feel the scoring would be too complicated otherwise; and I don't want Whitespace to be able to score 100%, because that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: The score seems to be Turing-undecidable in the general case when using an interpreter, and dependent on undocumented properties of compilers when using a compiler.

Comment: To everyone who is objecting to my crazy scoring rules, please comment/answer here: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/change-scoring-type-after-the-fact

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Ruby, 100% (74 characters)

Input on STDIN, output on STDOUT.

```
Vj=s=gets;puts(s.tr'!-~','P-~!-O');Vj;'lDl86EDjAFEDWD]ECVP\OV[V!\OP\~VXj;'
```

The second line is the first line ROT-47'd. Therefore, when ROT-47ing the whole program, it becomes:

```
';lDl86EDjAFEDWD]ECVP\OV[V!\OP\~VXj';jV=s=gets;puts(s.tr'!-~','P-~!-O');jV
```

My strategy here is based upon the fact that:

- `V` is `'` when ROT-47'd
- `j` is `;` when ROT-47'd
- Therefore, `Vj=...Vj;` turns into `';l...';`, which is essentially a no-op

  - Now you can create any arbitrary code that does anything normally and no-ops when ROT-47'd. This is because `Vj=...Vj;` can support running any code as you could do `Vj=0;{INSERT ANY CODE};Vj;`, and that will become `'...';` when ROT-47'd. You just have to be careful not to use `V` in that code, since that will break it.
- Similar logic can be used in reverse to produce the second half (`jV` instead of `Vj`)

Comment: okay you are correct I never specified that and I won't retroactively. However, spaces still do not count as eligible characters; this should be 136/140 I think.

Comment: @durron597 Fixed; no more spaces.

Comment: Dang ruby not requiring lines to end with a semicolon :)

Answer (score 16):

## C - 54.6%

```
Y;BW;XL;jNj;AW(){XL^Y;};main(int i,char**v){char*x=v[1];while(*x){if(*x>32&&*x<128)*x=(*x+15)%94+32;putchar(*x++);}}//Y^Nj>2:?W:?E :[492CYYGXL492CYIlG,`.jH9:=6WYIXL:7WYImbaUUYIk`agXYIlWYIZ`dXThcZbajAFE492CWYIZZXjNN
```

When ROT-47-translated, we get

```
*jq(j){j;};jp(WXL){/*jNj>2:?W:?E :[492CYYGXL492CYIlG,`.jH9:=6WYIXL:7WYImbaUUYIk`agXYIlWYIZ`dXThcZbajAFE492CWYIZZXjNN^^*/};main(int i,char**v){char*x=v[1];while(*x){if(*x>32&&*x<128)*x=(*x+15)%94+32;putchar(*x++);}}
```

Both programs compile, and ROT-47-translate the first argument:

```
$ ./a "hello world"
96==@ H@C=5
```

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work on ideone. I'm very impressed seeing a score above 50% though!

Comment: @durron597 It won't work on ideone as it accepts input via arguments, not stdin

Comment: Upvote for implementing ROT-47 for arguments, not just for self-translation. That should have been in the spec.

Answer (score 10):

### GolfScript, 120 / 120 bytes = 100%

```
{:&&32>&&+254<*{7+7+94%33+}*}%LiUUbamUUZadckYLfZfZhcTbbZNYNT
```

or, in ROT-47:

```
LiUUbamUUZadckYLfZfZhcTbbZNYNT{:&&32>&&+254<*{7+7+94%33+}*}%
```

No comments or string abuse.  The undefined command `LiUUbamUUZadckYLfZfZhcTbbZNYNT` (which equals the rest of the code in ROT-47) is a no-op, but it still gets executed by the interpreter, so I believe it counts as used.

This was actually a pretty easy challenge in GolfScript.  The main difficulty was in avoiding the digit `1`, which is mapped by ROT-47 into the GolfScript command `` ` ``.  The commands `.`, `-`, `,`, `\`, `[`, `/`, `]` and `^` also had to be avoided, but that was fairly easy in this case, since the task required no array building.

#### Bonus:

Here's a GolfScript [period-2 quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/golf-a-mutual-quine) (i.e. a program that prints a second program that prints the first program again) where the two programs are the ROT-47 transforms of each other:

```
{`'0$~'+.{7+7+94%33+}%@!{0$@@;}*}0$~L1V_SOVZ]LfZfZhcTbbZNToPL_SoojNYN_SO
```

This program outputs itself ROT-47 encoded, yielding another GolfScript program:

```
L1V_SOVZ]LfZfZhcTbbZNToPL_SoojNYN_SO{`'0$~'+.{7+7+94%33+}%@!{0$@@;}*}0$~
```

which, in turn, also outputs itself ROT-47 encoded, yielding the previous program again.  Thus, this program is also a [rotating quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/create-a-rotating-quine).

Comment: Your denominator is wrong: "divided by total bytes (all characters) of both versions". 60/120 = 50%

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre: All bytes in both versions are used (= executed by the interpreter), so that would be 120 / 120 = still 100%.

Comment: I'm unsure of the scoring because I don't know golfscript. I know that, for example, `A` in brainfuck would count in the numerator but not the denominator. Is this the same thing or different?

Comment: @durron597: `LiUUbamUUZadckYLfZfZhcTbbZNYNT` is a valid identifier in GolfScript, and will be executed as a command. However, it's not one of the [built-in commands](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html), nor is it assigned a meaning by the program, so by default it simply does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

## python, 96.1% (?)

According to your definition, strings count as used code?

```
V=input();print("".join([chr(33+(ord(V[i])+14)%94)for i in range(len(V))]));V
'l:?AFEWXjAC:?EWQQ];@:?W,49CWbbZW@C5WD,:.XZ`cXThcX7@C : :? C2?86W=6?WDXX.XXj'
```

Comment: In retrospect they shouldn't have, but it's far too late now