# It's Anagram Quine, not just Quine!

Tags: code-challenge, quine, source-layout, code-bowling, permutations

## The Task

In this challenge, your task is to write a program, which takes in no input, with as many anagrams that are quine of themselves as possible.

Your score will be the number of anagrams of your program's source code that are valid quines divided by the total number of anagrams possible, i.e. the percentage of the anagrams that are valid quines.

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) and [rules of standard quines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) apply.

**Note:** Your program must have at least 3 *characters* (not 3 bytes).

---

### Input

Each anagram (or permutation) of your program which is quine of itself (i.e. the anagrams which you are including in your score) must not take any input. If your language *requires* input as a necessity, then you can assume that your program will be given a String consisting of the lowercase letter A. However, you must not make any use of the input in any way.

---

### Output

`n` number of distinct anagrams of your program's source-code must be valid quines, where `n` represents the number of those anagrams that you are including in your score, i.e.

[image: Math Equation]

Those quine-anagarams can output in any way except writing the output to a variable. Writing to file, console, screen etc. is allowed. Function `return` is allowed as well.

---

### Scoring Example

Suppose your program's source code is `code`. And,

1. `code` outputs `code`.
2. `coed` outputs `coed`.
3. `cdoe` outputs `cdoe`.
4. `cdeo` outputs `cdeo`.
5. `cedo` outputs `cedo`.
6. `ceod` outputs `ceod`.
7. `ocde` outputs `ocde`.
8. `oced` outputs `oced`.
9. `odce` outputs `odce`.
10. `odec` does not output `odec` or produces error.
11. `oedc` does not output `oedc` or produces error.
12. `oecd` does not output `oecd` or produces error.
13. `doce` does not output `doce` or produces error.
14. `doec` does not output `doec` or produces error.
15. `dcoe` does not output `dcoe` or produces error.
16. `dceo` does not output `deco` or produces error.
17. `deco` does not output `deco` or produces error.
18. `deoc` does not output `deoc` or produces error.
19. `eodc` does not output `eodc` or produces error.
20. `eocd` does not output `eocd` or produces error.
21. `edoc` does not output `edoc` or produces error.
22. `edco` does not output `edco` or produces error.
23. `ecdo` does not output `ecdo` or produces error.
24. `ecod` does not output `ecod` or produces error.

The score of this solution will be

[image: Math Equation]

---

### Winning Criterion

The solution with the highest score wins! In case of a tie, the answer with higher char-count (not byte-count) wins (hence the [code-bowling](/questions/tagged/code-bowling))! If a tie still persists, then the solution which was posted earlier wins!

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121522/rotation-safe-quine

Comment: @NeilA. I'm a lot more confident that a rotation-safe quine can actually be written in other languages than Unary (although not in many languages and it will still be hard).

Comment: It's probably too late to change the specs now, but you should probably have specified that the original program doesn't count, because otherwise this essentially seems to be a duplicate of our vanilla quine question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Unary, 100%

This is essentially the same as the [Lenguage answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122068/38183) because of how the two are related. I think it's worth noting, though. I scored it as 100% because every permutation of the code will result in a quine of itself and I see that as X/X * 100 = 100%.

5.71728886e+3431 zeroes. The full number can be found in this snippet:

```html
571,728,886,299,524,079,667,110,831,585,172,705,903,242,988,869,730,233,666,941,239,930,957,383,634,990,884,017,758,011,673,661,456,375,420,014,789,453,910,279,412,516,365,039,911,616,569,776,194,653,994,845,706,814,330,810,597,741,840,830,026,333,447,578,878,492,702,908,613,882,908,168,867,637,282,596,648,914,407,902,821,648,635,054,942,485,156,519,086,239,517,305,702,705,783,520,430,327,882,724,649,323,623,993,252,952,774,346,675,694,385,891,810,563,667,798,834,846,369,950,692,136,274,353,903,969,878,343,229,031,870,459,050,270,140,433,402,333,183,995,076,273,934,316,316,041,923,055,208,568,854,697,194,015,046,079,301,420,468,901,769,118,098,230,767,460,924,846,552,476,679,293,134,684,448,847,449,288,151,944,932,525,087,248,192,275,095,934,337,598,653,981,534,386,220,451,824,875,829,915,842,538,357,082,913,137,430,485,883,178,947,004,702,124,084,633,123,544,060,730,650,995,512,745,030,590,989,195,409,454,379,726,020,068,090,543,485,377,485,846,396,271,958,108,709,617,635,354,477,293,970,464,272,097,575,501,779,386,668,756,938,340,200,794,894,015,824,708,091,428,944,573,831,257,244,094,409,870,775,301,993,104,432,870,895,478,408,037,450,837,230,273,086,589,639,225,269,690,034,191,664,788,952,560,282,035,550,980,217,998,364,096,267,637,012,870,557,015,775,372,943,770,232,826,937,792,678,659,741,977,391,285,036,126,978,266,614,181,473,074,907,458,591,514,305,961,253,806,814,023,933,864,985,407,267,169,604,856,107,931,116,888,268,748,039,451,683,353,551,414,447,462,928,850,923,445,503,652,021,793,168,648,510,513,597,305,336,955,173,718,471,931,736,313,986,020,652,567,023,366,257,316,037,210,037,318,158,858,503,724,736,280,981,391,398,280,363,850,853,361,932,459,586,164,155,418,666,917,331,478,035,204,211,067,642,357,524,068,995,687,396,230,593,421,768,310,516,964,395,591,974,018,305,173,396,770,508,740,001,527,520,092,344,197,005,623,355,537,596,657,473,766,544,801,370,212,627,256,410,732,664,011,822,421,191,103,127,619,073,582,845,123,484,719,578,718,376,300,070,162,355,969,718,786,766,544,705,666,866,547,241,576,008,751,585,319,953,584,072,266,931,915,765,118,041,170,749,844,694,686,800,072,822,536,450,477,293,767,227,280,278,303,598,479,313,816,303,539,184,630,996,668,979,230,004,925,749,414,158,627,159,671,600,379,023,203,894,575,932,729,998,748,035,419,783,450,180,418,397,923,824,642,227,478,374,530,825,875,117,414,862,969,170,359,605,774,864,660,165,183,532,258,493,867,754,625,154,388,052,741,695,648,070,594,472,531,159,793,952,847,078,816,841,601,345,611,759,202,959,380,748,999,978,577,549,942,317,774,738,570,775,404,426,481,919,733,186,968,468,431,270,431,605,972,498,637,946,956,126,022,229,614,797,087,117,225,823,565,342,748,501,153,741,450,722,494,697,466,495,557,622,414,355,168,111,360,033,562,039,346,636,733,121,121,610,857,454,876,606,487,443,794,811,222,591,756,267,144,914,006,412,918,432,311,781,300,777,103,610,374,114,091,997,695,742,108,877,002,082,862,282,098,075,681,749,979,978,446,425,489,037,395,541,763,956,873,201,738,020,809,689,085,082,333,652,677,837,122,632,903,083,224,964,125,736,624,491,672,540,404,024,051,399,430,701,347,505,739,704,581,760,444,853,708,889,328,730,053,965,944,499,104,791,856,210,999,740,898,398,825,918,657,619,888,095,865,548,102,735,913,913,094,386,735,714,696,418,726,741,576,678,447,905,375,266,819,534,780,270,705,492,733,528,843,064,273,668,310,355,948,806,085,914,998,909,078,430,123,434,842,644,353,766,593,108,209,757,731,578,915,664,389,676,321,477,765,937,156,616,387,196,395,610,946,243,206,146,663,560,610,797,140,874,906,254,178,018,061,181,083,047,209,661,789,909,286,724,851,898,477,573,800,702,633,601,175,620,396,600,949,134,122,178,276,685,812,142,120,568,127,180,096,273,903,971,758,009,993,201,718,908,993,673,764,199,386,800,398,143,178,502,530,082,660,500,014,722,964,981,864,977,851,706,298,981,882,062,478,994,083,243,364,559,882,663,594,491,418,634,537,443,259,947,411,981,605,363,306,172,530,522,346,606,185,828,881,879,282,631,498,937,150,281,652,951,729,913,616,393,089,658,674,346,663,853,707,461,126,940,124,422,764,766,614,384,500,640,200,165,833,857,590,144,741,546,981,402,879,612,572,412,230,319,659,934,882,344,598,744,566,237,876,680,653,747,327,784,600,034,796,624,136,727,679,072,247,471,775,907,417,517,609,655,422,229,860,544,695,004,718,249,668,190,489,544,232,936,202,367,307,609,329,582,839,156,431,588,444,789,676,252,562,273,585,535,627,566,417,124,298,941,319,814,273,113,830,010,077,536,882,402,273,792,934,052,604,658,425,046,299,684,558,311,449,368,519,016,440,435,219,777,519,127,752,414,574,327,366,464,226,160,312,027,143
```

The Brainf*ck equivalent is in this snippet:

```html
>+++++>++>++++++>+>+++++>+++++>+>++++++>+>+++++>+>++++++>+>+++++>+>++++++>+++>+++++>+++++>+>+++>++>+
+++>++++++>++>++++++>+++>+++++>++>++++++>++>+++++>++>++++++>+>+++++>+++++>+>++++++>+>+++++>+>++++++>
+>+++++>+>++++++>++>+++>+++++>+++++>+>+++>++>++++>++++++>++>++++++>+++>+++>+++>+++++>++>++++++>++>++
+++>++>++++++>+>++++>++++++>+>++++++>+>+++++>+>++++++>+>+++++>++++>+++++>++>+++>+>++++>++++++>+>++++
++>++>++>+++++>++>++++++>+>+++++>+++++>+++++>+>++++++>+>+++>++>++>+++++>++>++++++>+>++++>++++++>+>++
+++>+>++++++>+++>+>++++>+++++>++++>+++++>++++>+++++>++++>+++++>++++>+++++>++++>+++++>++++>++>++++>+>
+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>+>++++++>++>+++++>++++>+>+>
+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>++++++>+>++++++>++>++
+++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>++++++>+>+++
+++>++>+++++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>+++
+++>+>++++++>++>+++++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++++>++>++>++>+++++
+>++++++>+>++++++>++>+++++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+++++>++>++>++>
++++++>++++++>+>++++++>++>+++++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+>+>+>+++>+>+>+>+++>+++++>++>++>++
>++++++>++++++>++>+++++>++>++++++>+>++++++>+++>+++>++>+++>+++++>++>+++>+>+>+++++>+++++>+>+++>+>+++>+
+>++>++++>++++++>+>+++++>++>+++>+>++++>++++++>+>++++>+++++>++++>+++++>++++>+>+++++>+>+++>+>+++>++>++
>++++>++++++>+>+++++>++>+++>+>++++>++++++>+>+++++>++>+++>+>++++>+++++>++>++++>+>+++++>++++>++++++>++
++++>++++++>++>+++++>++++>++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>++>++>++>+++++>+++++>+>+>+>+++>++>++>++>+
+++>++++++>++>++>++>++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++>+++>++>++>++>+++>+++>+++>++>++>++>++++>++++>++++>++>++>++>+
++++>++>++>++>++++++>+>++++>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+>++++++>++>++>++++++>++++
++>+>++++++>++>++>++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>+>+++++>++>++>+++>+>+++>+>++++>++++++>++>++>+++++>+>+>+++
>++>++>++++>++++++>+>+++++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+++++>+>+++>+>+++>++>++>++++>++++++>+>+++++>++>+++>+>+++
+>++++++>+>++++>+++++>++>+++>+>++++>+++++>++>++++>+>++++>++++++>++>+++++>++++>++>++++>++++>+>+>+>+++
++>+>+>+>++++++>++>++>++>+++++>+++++>+>+>+>+++>++>++>++>++++>++++++>++>++>++>++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++>++
+>++>++>++>++>++>++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>+>++++>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+++>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>++>++
>++++++>+>++++++>+>++++++>++>++>++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>++++++>+>+++++>++>++>+++>+>+++>+>++++>+++++
+>++>++>+++++>+>+>+++>++>++>++++>++++++>+>+++++>++++>+>+>+>+++++>+++++>+>+++>+>+++>++>++>++++>++++++
>+>+++++>++>+++>+>++++>++++++>+++>+>++++>+++++>++>++++>+>+++++>++++>++++++>++++++>++>+++++>++++>++>+
+++>++>++>++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>+>++++>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>++++++>+>+>+>+++++>+++++>++>++>++>+++>+>+>
+>++++>++++++>+>+>+>++++++>++>++>++>++>++>++++++>+>+>++++++>++>++>++>+++++>++>++>++>++++++>++++++>+>
+++++>+>++++>++>++++>++++++>+>++++++>+>+++++>+++>+++>+++>+++++>+>+++>+++>+++>+++>+++>+++>+++>+++>++>
++++>++++++>+>+++++++>+>+>++++++[<]>[[>]>[>]>[>]+[[>+<-]<]+[<]<[<]>[[>]>[>]>[>]<+[[>+<-]<]+++[<]<[<]
>-]>]>[>]>[-[<+>-]>]<<[<]>[[[>]>+<<[<]>-]>[>]+>-[-[-[-[-[-[-<->>>[>>>]++>>>+>>>+[<<<]>]<[->>>[>>>]++
>>>++>>>++[<<<]]>]<[->>>[>>>]++>>>++>>>+[<<<]]>]<[->>>[>>>]+>>>++>>>++[<<<]]>]<[->>>[>>>]+>>>++>>>+[
<<<]]>]<[->>>[>>>]+>>>+>>>++[<<<]]>]<[->>>[>>>]+>>>+>>>+[<<<]]<[<]>]++
%
<+[<+>>[[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]>-[-[->[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]>[<+>-[<->[-]]]<[-<->>>[>>>]<<<[[>>>+<<<-]<<<]>>>+++<
<<+++<<<---<<<[<<<]>->>[>>>]+[>>>]>]<<]]>]<<<[<<<]>[<<+>+>-]<<[>>+<<-]>[->>>[[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]>-[<+>-
[<->-]<[-<-->>>[>>>]<<<[[>>>+<<<-]<<<]>>>+++<<<<<<[<<<]>->>[>>>]+[>>>]<<]>]>]<<<[<<<]]>[<<+>+>-]<<[>
>+<<-]>[->>>[[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]+>-[<->[-]]<[-<-<<<[<<<]>->>[>>>]>>>[[<<<+>>>-]>>>]<<<<<]>>]<<<[<<<]]>[
>-<-]>]>[+++[>++++++++<-]>.>>]
```

[Source of source](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Talk:Unary#A_quine_in_Unary)

Comment: Congratulations on winning! :)

Comment: @Arjun Thanks but the Legrange answer was first and has the same score. It should win, instead.

Comment: @EngineerToast I mean it doesn't matter to me, it is CW so no +15 :P

Answer (score 4):

## Lenguage, 100%

5.71728886e+3431 null bytes. The full number can be found in this snippet:

```html
571728886299524079667110831585172705903242988869730233666941239930957383634990884017758011673661456375420014789453910279412516365039911616569776194653994845706814330810597741840830026333447578878492702908613882908168867637282596648914407902821648635054942485156519086239517305702705783520430327882724649323623993252952774346675694385891810563667798834846369950692136274353903969878343229031870459050270140433402333183995076273934316316041923055208568854697194015046079301420468901769118098230767460924846552476679293134684448847449288151944932525087248192275095934337598653981534386220451824875829915842538357082913137430485883178947004702124084633123544060730650995512745030590989195409454379726020068090543485377485846396271958108709617635354477293970464272097575501779386668756938340200794894015824708091428944573831257244094409870775301993104432870895478408037450837230273086589639225269690034191664788952560282035550980217998364096267637012870557015775372943770232826937792678659741977391285036126978266614181473074907458591514305961253806814023933864985407267169604856107931116888268748039451683353551414447462928850923445503652021793168648510513597305336955173718471931736313986020652567023366257316037210037318158858503724736280981391398280363850853361932459586164155418666917331478035204211067642357524068995687396230593421768310516964395591974018305173396770508740001527520092344197005623355537596657473766544801370212627256410732664011822421191103127619073582845123484719578718376300070162355969718786766544705666866547241576008751585319953584072266931915765118041170749844694686800072822536450477293767227280278303598479313816303539184630996668979230004925749414158627159671600379023203894575932729998748035419783450180418397923824642227478374530825875117414862969170359605774864660165183532258493867754625154388052741695648070594472531159793952847078816841601345611759202959380748999978577549942317774738570775404426481919733186968468431270431605972498637946956126022229614797087117225823565342748501153741450722494697466495557622414355168111360033562039346636733121121610857454876606487443794811222591756267144914006412918432311781300777103610374114091997695742108877002082862282098075681749979978446425489037395541763956873201738020809689085082333652677837122632903083224964125736624491672540404024051399430701347505739704581760444853708889328730053965944499104791856210999740898398825918657619888095865548102735913913094386735714696418726741576678447905375266819534780270705492733528843064273668310355948806085914998909078430123434842644353766593108209757731578915664389676321477765937156616387196395610946243206146663560610797140874906254178018061181083047209661789909286724851898477573800702633601175620396600949134122178276685812142120568127180096273903971758009993201718908993673764199386800398143178502530082660500014722964981864977851706298981882062478994083243364559882663594491418634537443259947411981605363306172530522346606185828881879282631498937150281652951729913616393089658674346663853707461126940124422764766614384500640200165833857590144741546981402879612572412230319659934882344598744566237876680653747327784600034796624136727679072247471775907417517609655422229860544695004718249668190489544232936202367307609329582839156431588444789676252562273585535627566417124298941319814273113830010077536882402273792934052604658425046299684558311449368519016440435219777519127752414574327366464226160312027143
```

Comment: @ETHproductions fixed it. I think I win

Comment: Would this output 5.71728886e+3431 *null* bytes or something else?

Comment: @ETHproductions Yeah I guess.

Comment: Made CW because I may not be around to remove this :P

Comment: @Christopher You should include the precise amount of bytes so that this can be decoded.  There is currently no way to tell what this does.

Comment: @WheatWizard view revisions

Comment: It would also be nice if you included the Brainfuck program that this compiles into.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 So infinity score :D.

Comment: @Christopher I don't think the original program should count as an anagram of itself, but I reread the OP and the OP seems to be allowing it.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Yeah it is unclear. But X/0 = infinity

Comment: Why isn't the score X/X = 100% ?

Comment: Unary and Lenguage use different binary encodings of Brainfuck programs. It's unlikely the quine would work in both Unary and Lenguage.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 33.333...%

```
”ṘṘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYe7DnTOA6P9/AA)

Community wiki because I did not write this. If you like this solution, or want an explanation, see [Dennis's original post here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73930/31716).

Answer (score 2):

## Microscript II, score 1/1814399=5.5e-7

```
"qp1h"qp1h
```

`"qph1"qph1` is also a quine.

## Microscript II, score 5/119750399=4.2e-8

```
"qp12h"qp12h
```

`"qp21h"qp21h`, `"qph12"qph12`, `"qph21"qph21`, `"qp1h2"qp1h2` and  `"qp2h1"qp2h1` are also quines.

I'm sure someone can come up with a much higher score than either of these, but this is still the only answer with at least one quine that isn't the original program (which, IMO, shouldn't be counted).

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 16.666...%

```
2i2i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@2@UaZT5/z8A)

There are 6 possible anagrams of this code:

```
2i2i
22ii
i22i
i2i2
ii22
2ii2
```

And one of them is a quine.

Comment: I'm not sure the original program should count as an anagram of itself, but the OP seems to be allowing it.